# Limit options when creating content according to selected value

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have three content types, `Events`, `Disciplines` and `Championships`. An `Event` has [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)s to `Disciplines` and `Championships` and `Championship` has an entity reference to `Disciplines`.

```
 ----- 1..n    1..n ------------
|Event|------------|Championship|
 -----              ------------
   |0..n               |0..n
   |                   |
   |                   |
   |1..n               |
 ---------- 1          |
|Discipline|-----------/
 ----------
```

When users are creating new `Event` nodes they initially select which `Disciplines` are involved from a list of checkboxes and then similarly the `Championship`(s) involved.

At the moment all `Championships` nodes appear, allowing users to potentially select `Championships` for `Disciplines` which are not part of the `Event`.

Is it possible to use the [conditional fields](https://drupal.org/project/Conditional_Fields) module to create a dependency to display only `Championships` where the `Championship`'s Discipline field matches the `Discipline`(s) selected when the dependency is triggered?

How would one fill the 'Set of values' in the conditional fields module?

For example when creating `Event1`, I select `DisciplineA` and `DisciplineB`. The list of `Championships` should only contain those which have `DisciplineA` or `DisciplineB` associations and not contain any `Championships` that do not have the correct associations

if event.disciplines were a list of selected disciplines I'd like something along these lines (with the dynamic aspects of conditional fields)

`SELECT championships c WHERE c.discipline IN (event.disciplines)`

**edit**

[Dependent Fields](https://drupal.org/project/dependent_fields) seems to do the sort of thing i'd like but there's no D7 version...

**edit 2**

Changed the structure a little.

I suppose `Discipline` didn't need to be an entity in itself and have created a taxonomy vocabulary Discipline instead with terms for each discipline. `Event` and `Championship` now have term references to the same `field_discipline`.

Using the [Reference field limit option](https://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module the `Championship` entity reference in `Event` has the 'Limit this field's options according to the matching field values' option selected and the matching field being `discipline (field_discipline)`.

When creating an `Event` the list of `Championships` is empty but when I select the `Discipline(s)` the expected `Championships` do not appear.

`No options are available for the current form values. Try selecting different values for the following fields: discipline.`

**edit 3...**

Firebug suggested that the ajax wasn't actually firing for checkbox/radio button but was for select menu. Applied [this patch](https://drupal.org/files/2006798-16.reference_option_limit.ajax-elements.patch) and the section is now updating but still not finding any values. There are appropriate `Championship` nodes to find.

**edit 4!**

The `Championship` nodes didn't have the discipline taxonomies selected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way i found to do this uses entity references, reference option limit and views modules.

```
  -----               ----
 |Event|-------------|Race|
  -----  1..*    1..* ----
   *|                  |*
    |                  |
  1 |                  |
 --------- 1           |
|Organiser|------------/
 ---------
```

An `Event` is made up of `Races`
An `Organiser` can organise `Event`(s) and/or `Races` according to two Boolean fields Event? and Race? in the `Organiser` content type.

When creating, for example, an `Event` node we want only the possible options to be those `Organiser` nodes with Event? field set to 'true'.

Assuming the content types already defined, with `Event` having an entity reference to `Orgainser`, first create a new view...

In this case I called the view 'Event Organisers - Limit Options' and set it to **show Content** of type `Organiser`. Untick create Page then click **Continue & edit**.

With the blank Master view, click **+ Add** and select 'Entity Reference'.

Add the field Event? to the **FIELDS**

In the *Format* Settings select the Event? field.

In the **FILTER CRITERIA** add Event? and set **Operator** to `is one of` and select `true` from the **Options**.

Then edit the Entity Reference field in the `Event` content type which links to `Organiser` type.

**Entity Selection** in **Mode** select 'Views:Filter by an entity reference view' then select the newly created view.

This is obviously applicable to any use case and seems a simple enough way to implement. I did pretty much exactly the same to limit available race organisers too.

Hope this helps someone, i spent quite a while scratching my head over this...

Answer (score 1):

I got this sorted (eventually...)

Rather than having `Discipline` as a content type (since it was only really storing the name) I created a taxonomy vocabulary called Discipline and added all the relevant discipline names as terms.

Removed the entity references to `Discipline` in `Event` and `Championship`. Added a term reference (`field_discipline`) to `Event` and the **same** term reference to `Championship`.

Using the Reference Option Limit module (and patch; see question) in the entity reference in `Event` to `Championship` added the 'Limit this field's options according to matching field values' and selected the matching field `field_discipline`.

So now when creating an Event node the user is presented with a list of checkboxes to select the discipline(s) involved and when each is selected the appropriate championships are added to the list of available championships.